# iptables causing external sites to have problems when connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, iptables

Recently I've managed to block all unused ports on my dedicated server (Linux CentOS latest 64-bit) but whenever I do so, sites that connect to my database just simply cannot connect.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

I believe it has something to do with the OUTPUT port, but I am not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow remote incoming mysql connections you will need to define an INPUT rule that is not isolated to your local interface:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

In Centos this will be defined in the **/etc/sysconfig/iptables**  file.  Then restart:

```
sudo service iptables restart
```

Alternatively, from the command line,  you can use:

```
sudo system-config-firewall-tui
```

To configure your firewall,  it is in the package of the same name:

```
sudo yum install system-config-firewall-tui -y
```